# Show a alert when the user close the window when the audio is playing

Tags: javascript, jquery, mediaelement

I use the MediaElement.js framework to build my audio players...
But, is a podcast and is normal see users closing the window accidentally.

I'm searching for scripts to this, but absolutely nothing works.

How alert the user when he close the window with the player working...?

If is playing: ask if the user really want this.
If the player isn't playing: close the window..

Comment: Some code might help. It just might.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add an event as follows:

```
$(window).bind("beforeunload", function(evt) {//gets called before the user leaves the page
    //check if audio is already running
    if(isPlayingAudio()) {
        //shows a confirm message asking user if they want to stay
        return "Are you sure you want to leave while playing music?";
    }
})
```

If your elements are on the page and not stored in javascript

```
function isPlayingAudio() {
    var $playing = $('audio').filter(function(i, $audio) {//all audio not paused
        return !$audio.prop('paused');
    });
    return $playing.length === 0;//no audio elements are playing...
}
```

Comment: Isn't working here. 

How to use this code with HTML5 player and MediaElement.js?

Comment: I don't know your code so I can't help you with that - all this is checking `app.audioIsPlaying` - or some other variable - which you are responsible for. You set this to true when an audio element starts playin and false when it stops. Alternatively keep track of all your aduio elements and check to see if any are not `paused`

Comment: I'm using the html5 audio player.
`<audio controls="control" id="podplayer" preload="none" src="example.mp3" type="audio/mp3"></audio>`

If is playing, show a alert asking if the user want stay or quit.
If isn't playing, just quit.

I tried using many forms, but nothing works. Thanks.

Comment: Audio elements are `paused` when they aren't playing afaik. You can check if all audio elements are paused. i cant help you if your case is more complex than this as I'm coding with my hands in the air